# Authentication in Spring Cloud Gateway through Cookies(Session ID)

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying convert one zuul gateway to spring cloud gateway, Previously we sent cookie with session id (keycloak) from UI , zuul automatically authenticates the request and sent to microservice, but in case of Spring Cloud Gateway we are getting the Authentication Object as null

Can some gave an idea ? Getting context from

```
ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
```

```
ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
    .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
    .doOnNext(auth -> log.debug("Authentication:{}",String.valueOf(auth)))
    .subscribe();

Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
log.debug("authentication is {}", authentication);
```

The first case it is not getting any Authentication object and 2nd case it is null

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Keycloak, you might have OAuth2 `access`, `ID` and `refresh` tokens in addition to session ID.

I'd build client (UI) and resource (REST API) servers security with Spring-security OAuth2 implementation: using access-token for resources access control (and maybe ID token to access user info from UI, but not sure this is applicable to ZK). If your projects support boot, those are `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` libs.

You can find samples mapping Keycloak roles to Spring authorities for a resource-server in [this tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials). For reactive apps, you'll have to dig into [samples](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples) and my own spring-boot starters for [JWT decoder](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/webflux/spring-addons-webflux-jwt-resource-server/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/config/reactive/AddonsWebSecurityBeans.java) or [introspection](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/webflux/spring-addons-webflux-introspecting-resource-server/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/config/reactive/AddonsWebSecurityBeans.java) source code (or just use the starters as done in samples, that would save you quite some efforts).